# Two arrays using same memory address

Tags: assembly

The lab asked to go from big Endian to little endian order. I get the desire results, but a temp array uses the same address as my little endian, doubling the content. How, can I fix it? I'm new to assembly language

Here is my code:

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.data
bigEndian BYTE 12h,34h,56h,78h ;given code do not delete
littleEndian DWORD ?

tempArray BYTE ?


.code
main proc

    mov ebx,0
    mov ecx,4
    mov esi, SIZEOF bigEndian -1


L1: 

    mov dl,bigEndian[esi]
    mov tempArray[ebx], dl
    dec esi
    inc ebx


    loop L1

    mov esi,0
    mov eax,DWORD PTR tempArray[esi]
    mov littleEndian,eax
    ;inc esi


    invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

Comment: Side note - since this is .386 and not .486 or later, BSWAP can't be used.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a temp array. You can use something like this (MASM syntax):

```
        mov     esi,offset bigEndian         
        lodsb
        shl     eax,8
        lodsb
        shl     eax,8
        lodsb
        shl     eax,8
        lodsb
        mov     littleEndian,eax
```

If the assignment is to do this just using mov instructrions, and no shift instructions (MASM syntax):

```
        mov     al,byte ptr bigEndian+0
        mov     byte ptr littleEndian+3,al
        mov     al,byte ptr bigEndian+1
        mov     byte ptr littleEndian+2,al
        mov     al,byte ptr bigEndian+2
        mov     byte ptr littleEndian+1,al
        mov     al,byte ptr bigEndian+3
        mov     byte ptr littleEndian+0,al
```

or

```
        mov     ah,byte ptr bigEndian+0
        mov     al,byte ptr bigEndian+1
        mov     word ptr littleEndian+2,ax
        mov     ah,byte ptr bigEndian+2
        mov     al,byte ptr bigEndian+3
        mov     word ptr littleEndian+0,ax
```

Comment: The question for the assignment is as: Converting from Big Endian to Little Endian
Write a program that uses the variables below and MOV instructions to copy the value from
bigEndian to littleEndian, reversing the order of the bytes. The number’s 32-bit value is understood
to be 12345678 hexadecimal.
.data
bigEndian BYTE 12h,34h,56h,78h
littleEndian DWORD ?"

Comment: The place I found it was in this book put on a profs site: http://profmsaeed.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/IntelAsseblyLanguage.pdf . Just look for the question in the PDF file.

Comment: Now we agree on the 6 `mov` solution. I guess enough editing ;-)

Comment: @rcgldr Your first code snippet is wrong. Due to an extra `shl eax, 8` your solution looses the first *bigEndian* byte.

Comment: @rcgldr I don't understand the ratio for your 2nd and 3rd code snippets after reading the intervening paragraph which talks about **not** using *littleEndian*.

Comment: @user3144770 - lost an edit on the first example, it's fixed now. If you read the problem statement from [profmsaeed's pdf file](http://profmsaeed.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/IntelAsseblyLanguage.pdf), it defines bigEndian and littleEndian as shown in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use a temp array for this task.

- In-place reversing only using `MOV` instructions.

  ```
  mov esi, 0
  mov edi, 3
  L1: 
  mov dl, bigEndian[esi]
  mov dh, bigEndian[edi]
  mov bigEndian[edi], dl
  mov bigEndian[esi], dh
  inc esi
  dec edi
  cmp esi, edi
  jb L1
  ```
- If the destination is indeed another variable then use this:

  ```
  mov esi, 3
  mov edi, 0
  L1: 
  mov dl, bigEndian[esi]
  mov littleEndian[edi], dl
  inc edi
  dec esi
  jns L1
  ```

Comment: The problem statement is "using mov instructions", although it's not clear if that means only mov instructions are allowed, which would exclude inc, dec, jmp, ... .